# Top fans of a fanpage. The highest interaction of fans?

Tags: facebook, interaction

Is it possible to catch fans of a fanpage within the highest interaction on a fanpage?

Comment: it think it is... but you'll have to run very fast ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless you somehow measure the interaction yourself (like counting the number of likes, posts, comments and so on).

As far as I know, there is no easy solution to access such data directly from a Facebook api